# PhoneGap GeoLocation var types

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, geolocation

```
//   This method accepts a `Position` object, which contains
//   the current GPS coordinates
function onSuccess(position) {
    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
    element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '               + position.coords.latitude                                 + '<br />' +
                            'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '<br />' +
                            'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +
                            'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '<br />' +
                            'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '<br />' +
                            'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading               + '<br />' +
                            'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '<br />' +
                            'Timestamp: '          +                                         position.timestamp             + '<br />';
}
```

it is example taken from phonegap's own site about geoLocation but there is some issue i cant understand quietly, we use position variable object for reach coords' members like lantitude,lontitude but how can we create Position object in js,even there are not something variable types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "position" var is created by Phonegap and pass to the callback success function when you do a :

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
```

The onSuccess function :

```
function onSuccess(position) {
    //Process the position here
}
```

The full example from the Phonegap api documentation :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Exemple Geolocation</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.3.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Attendre que PhoneGap soit prêt
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap est prêt
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    }

    // Fonction de callback onSuccess, reçoit un objet Position
    //
    function onSuccess(position) {
        var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
        element.innerHTML = 'Latitude : '                + position.coords.latitude          + '<br/>' +
                            'Longitude : '               + position.coords.longitude         + '<br/>' +
                            'Altitude : '                + position.coords.altitude          + '<br/>' +
                            'Précision : '               + position.coords.accuracy          + '<br/>' +
                            'Précision de l'altitude : ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '<br/>' +
                            'Direction : '               + position.coords.heading           + '<br/>' +
                            'Vitesse : '                 + position.coords.speed             + '<br/>';
    }

    // Fonction de callback onError, reçoit un objet PositionError
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code : '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message : ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="geolocation">Recherche de géolocalisation...</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps ! Bye !

Comment: No problem :) ! Don't forget to mark this answer as resolving the question.

Comment: do u know how can i do that?

Comment: Mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. See : [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)